# xhtml2pdf in django - issue link_callback

Tags: django-templates, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to generate a pdf from an html-template in django. Therefore i use pretty much the basic methods found in the web. The issue is that in can get it to generate the content of my template, but not the images from my media directory. I always get the following error:

SuspiciousFileOperation at /manager/createpdf/

The joined path is located outside of the base path component

Since i can get some result, i assume that nothing is wrong with my view. Here is my render_to_pdf

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):

template = get_template(template_src)
html  = template.render(context_dict)
result = BytesIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result, link_callback=link_callback)

if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')

return None
```

and the link_callback:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):

result = finders.find(uri)
if result:
    if not isinstance(result, (list, tuple)):
        result = [result]
    result = list(os.path.realpath(path) for path in result)
    path=result[0]
else:
    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL        
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT     
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL         
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return uri

    # make sure that file exists
if not os.path.isfile(path):    
    raise Exception( 'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))

return path
```

I am pretty much sure that the link_callback doesnt do it's purpose. But my knowledge is to little to patch it. I also assume that i configured the media directory correctly. I can access the media files in other views/templates.

Help is very appreciated, since i spend quiet some hours on this issue... A big thx to all the are going to contribute here!

Answer (score 0):

OK, i found it! In the finders.py i checked the find-method. It turns out that the find method only looks for files in the static directory and disregards the media directory. i just deleted all the lins and it works now. Here is the code:

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):

sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL
sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT
mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL
mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

if uri.startswith(mUrl):
    path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
    path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
else:
    return uri

if not os.path.isfile(path):    
    raise Exception( 'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))

return path
```

Answer (score 0):

Many devs ping me with the same problem. I will add a more complex explanation.

## In few words

A quick answer is, you need to use absolute paths instead of relative (static function returns relative).

## Detailed answer

### 1. The `link_callback` Function

The `link_callback` function helps `xhtml2pdf` to locate and use static assets. It's essential to handle both development (`DEBUG=True`) and production (`DEBUG=False`) environments.

```py
import os
from django.conf import settings

def link_callback(uri, rel):
    if os.path.isabs(uri):
        return uri

    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))
    else:
        return uri

    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))
    return path
```

### 2. Function to Render HTML to PDF

This function converts a given Django HTML template and context into a PDF response:

```py
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.http import HttpResponse
import io

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="output.pdf"'
    
    pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)

    if pisa_status.err:
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors <pre>' + html + '</pre>')
    return response
```

### 3. Django View

A Django view that uses the `render_to_pdf` function to render a provided template as a PDF:

```py
def generate_pdf(request):
    context = {'some_data': 'Hello, World!'}
    return render_to_pdf('pdf_template.html', context)
```

### 4. HTML Template (`pdf_template.html`)

A sample HTML template with static references:

```html
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PDF Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'jobs/css/style.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to My PDF</h1>
    <p>This is a sample PDF generated using xhtml2pdf.</p>
    <img src="{% static 'jobs/images/sample.jpg' %}" alt="Sample Image">
</body>
</html>
```

### 5. URL Configuration

Connect the `generate_pdf` view to a URL:

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import generate_pdf

urlpatterns = [
    path('generate-pdf/', generate_pdf, name='generate_pdf'),
]
```

## Integration Steps:

1. Place the `link_callback` and `render_to_pdf` functions in a suitable utilities or views file in your Django app.
2. Create your desired HTML template, embedding or linking any necessary static assets with the `{% static %}` tag.
3. Set up a view that uses the `render_to_pdf` function to generate the PDF.
4. Add a URL route to trigger this view.
5. Ensure that if `DEBUG` is set to `False`, you run `collectstatic` to gather all static files in the location specified by `STATIC_ROOT`.

Now, navigating to the `/generate-pdf/` endpoint (or whatever URL you've set up) will generate a PDF based on the `pdf_template.html` template. Static assets (like CSS and images) will be embedded correctly thanks to the `link_callback` function.